# Change layout of a ConfirmDialog depending on users choises

Tags: java, swing

I have a program which registers `Cows`, `Dogs` and `Cats` of the superclass Animal into a `DataCollection` of some sort. The user presses a button "Add animal" and from there I would like to open a `ConfirmDialog` with a `JPanel` as parameter that first only had 3 checkboxes: `Cow[]` - `Dog[]` - `Cat[]` and depending on what the user picks add the appropriate textfields for the data this type of animal needs.

Is there a way to add a listener for when a checkbox gets "checked" and then just add the new fields that i want for that type, or is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: *"If I had a program [...]"* enough reason to downvote!

Comment: I do have a program. I thought that this problem had very little to do with my code though, since from what I can see my problem evolves around a way of thinking rather than syntax.

Comment: Did you try adding some listeners?

Comment: Yes (actionlistener), so now I want to add a few textfields and labels depending on which box is checked, and I want do add them to the already open window(confirmdialog)

Answer (score 0):

For each animal type, create a panel with specialized input components, and place all three panels in a separate JPanel that uses a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html).  CardLayout displays one and only one of its children at any given time;  each child is identified by a String identifier of your choosing, which you must specify when you add the child.

This is better than adding components dynamically, because CardLayout will always make sure a container's preferred size is large enough to accommodate all of the children, so the dialog won't shuffle things around when you change which components are visible.

```
private static final String COW_CARD_ID = "cow";
private static final String DOG_CARD_ID = "dog";
private static final String CAT_CARD_ID = "cat";

void buildConfirmDialog() {

    JPanel cowFieldsPanel = new JPanel();
    // Add cow-specific components here

    JPanel dogFieldsPanel = new JPanel();
    // Add dog-specific components here

    JPanel catFieldsPanel = new JPanel();
    // Add cat-specific components here

    final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    final JPanel animalSpecificFieldsPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
    animalSpecificFieldsPanel.add(cowFieldsPanel, COW_CARD_ID);
    animalSpecificFieldsPanel.add(dogFieldsPanel, DOG_CARD_ID);
    animalSpecificFieldsPanel.add(catFieldsPanel, CAT_CARD_ID);

    JRadioButton cowButton = // ...
    JRadioButton dogButton = // ...
    JRadioButton catButton = // ...

    cowButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                cardLayout.show(animalSpecificFieldsPanel, COW_CARD_ID);
            }
        }
    });

    dogButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                cardLayout.show(animalSpecificFieldsPanel, DOG_CARD_ID);
            }
        }
    });

    catButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                cardLayout.show(animalSpecificFieldsPanel, CAT_CARD_ID);
            }
        }
    });

    ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup.add(cowButton);
    buttonGroup.add(dogButton);
    buttonGroup.add(catButton);
}
```

It's probably worth mentioning that when expecting a user to choose exactly one item from a list of many items, you should use radio buttons, not checkboxes.  In Swing, JRadioButtons are almost always added to a single common ButtonGroup so they will have that one-of-many functionality.